# Java image loading path issue

Tags: java, image, path

So i need to load images and place them on jButtons.

```
    ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
```

i can only load images that are also in the project folder and after compiling they are in the jar
the problem here is i can not load other images from outside the jar

```
   ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon(path);
```

with that i can load up images from outside the jar but not anymore the images that are in the jar.

is there a way to combine those things? i need a function that can load up images with a relative path from the jar and a absoluth path from the harddrive

Comment: Check the given path. If it exists on the hard drive, load the image in the second method. If not, in the first method.

Comment: I guess you as the developer should know if the path is a resource in the JAR file or not (user provided path or whatever)? So you can just create a helper method and pass a flag variable to it maybe. Or where do you get the path(s) from?

Comment: oh ok gonny try it out